# Calculating percentage filtering by rows which have the same key (groups of rows)

Tags: powerbi, survey

I have survey data, a database of student's evaluations of their professors for each course they took on a given semester. Each row is basically a questionnaire, containing a single student's evaluation. Columns carry data about which professor, on which course and at what time, and the questions asked. Its a flat table, with nearly 70k rows per semester.

In the end, i have to be able to calculate the percentage of positive values within each group (likert scale, only considering value 3 and 4 as positive mentions). Each group (or course, basically) is defined by a composite key (course id, section, year, semester, teacher id) which i've put in a calculated column as a string. Each resulting group key is a value on a row, repeated for those rows that pertain to the same group (so that i end up with, say, 20 students evaluating a professor on a course, having the same group key)

My brain is fried, i've tried unpivoting question columns, using declared variables to hold the temporary values, calculate using filters, but i've ended up with nothing. Any assistance or experience of this sort of analysis would be helpful. I can provide sample data if required.

Hope you guys have a better day than i'm having lol

Comment: Could you please provide a table with a few rows of sample data? Formulating a clear question would be helpful, too. – What is the problem you're trying to solve? Also: What technology are you working with? Are you looking for a SQL query?

Comment: Right. I'll clarify in a moment, and give you guys a sample